# Drawing Image in Canvas using DataURL

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, src

I am trying to create 3 canvas.

- The first canvas consist of image1.
- The second canvas consist of image2.
- The third canvas is a canvas that I want to use javascript to draw the image1 from DataURL().

However, I couldn't able to draw it. Is there anything I did wrong?

HTML code

```
<body>
<img id="image1" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e39d18b89822d1d9871e0d1bc839d06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<img id="image2" src="http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png">
<canvas id="myCanvas2"></canvas>


<canvas id="myCanvas3"></canvas>

</body>
```

Javescript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var a = c.toDataURL();
alert(a);

var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.src = a;
ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
```

Comment: did you try the `onload` method ?
`img.onload = function(){ ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20); };` after `img.src=a; `

Comment: @mohkhan ya, I tried, but still failed. 
Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/khongming/ZQ5Z3/
The alert show the dataURL() is working.

Comment: how do you get any image data in to `myCanvas` first canvas?

Comment: why don't you just ctx.drawImage(c,20,30) instead of using the slow dataURL() procedure?

Comment: @VeXii From here `var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var a = c.toDataURL();` I get the `DataURL` from the `myCanvas`. 
The whole purpose of my experiment is to draw the image from `DataURL`

Comment: @dandavis I totally understand that using `ctx.drawImage(c,20,30)` can show the image directly. 

I am experimenting to draw image in canvas from `DataURL` as I am storing the image into database as `DataURL` and retrieve back as `DataURL` before I can draw into image.

Comment: @KhongMingKok i can see that. but youre pulling an DataURL from a EMPTY canvas. so youre not going to see anything but white. if you wanner see whith a propper picture or an data url i left examples for that

Comment: Sorry if I can't understand.
I am pulling the `DataURL` from "myCanvas", to be sure, I log and show in alert of `var a`. The `DataURL` is there, so it is not suppose to be empty right?

Comment: @KhongMingKok the DataURL youre alerting is the Data of an empty (as in all Transparent) picture.

Comment: Thank you so much @VeXii . How dumb am I. I thought the alert was the Data URL of my image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

youre missing the `onload` event of the image:

```
var image = new Image
image.src = "URL or DataURL"
image.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(image)
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwCH8/3/)

Comment: thank you,. I just notice that I did not use the image.onload().
However, I am drawing use the DataURL as the source, but it won't work and you are demonstrating draw from using websource.

Comment: it works fine with DataURL's just make sure youre canvas1 arnt empty

[Check this updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwCH8/2/)

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't the accepted answer (put src as last line to be 100% safe). +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

The first canvas is empty and that's why nothing gets drawn on the third one. Do this first.

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e39d18b89822d1d9871e0d1bc839d06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
```

You have to draw an image on a canvas. Just be having an img tag before the canvas tag will not draw the image on your canvas element.

Comment: This will potentially fail. Don't draw right after setting src, but use the onload event on the image to make sure the image is actually completely loaded.